# Improve our Cricket Team

Tags: rules, cricket, training

I am captain of cricket team in my college our team performance is very well but some team members are play only for fun at that result our team lose best performance at regional level matches.

Actually those members are my best friends therefore I do not react on his performance. My friends played very well but some time he plays out of rules.
 How to improve our team discipline. What should I do with my friends to achieve our team goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I do with my friends to achieve our team goal.

What *is* your team goal? It seems that the members of your team have at least two, and maybe three different goals:

- Your friends who are playing for fun. They care less about whether they win or lose and more about enjoying themselves.
- Your one teammate who is prepared to break the rules (actually cheat?) in order to win.
- You, who are somewhere in the middle and want to win but fairly?

With the exception of any actual cheating, *none of these are wrong*. It's perfectly valid to play for fun, it's perfectly valid to play to win... but it's very hard to have a happy team if the members have different goals.